# How to change the index of a series? Series don't have the set_index method

Tags: python, pandas, series

Unlike dataframes, series do not have the set_index method - which begs the question: if we want to change the index, how do we do it?

Accessing series.index works, but I seemed to remember it wasn't recommended?

I could convert to a dataframe, use the set_index method, then convert back to series, but it seems convoluted.

**EDIT**: I do not want to reindex, but to set a new index. As explained in the docs https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html

> By default values in the new index that do not have corresponding
> records in the dataframe are assigned NaN.

That is NOT what I need. What I need is:

```
+---------------+-----------+
| Current index | New Index |
+---------------+-----------+
|             1 |         4 |
|             2 |         5 |
|             3 |         6 |
+---------------+-----------+
```

A toy example:

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(data =['a','b','c'])

#this works
s.index = [4,5,6]

# this doesn't work
s = s.set_index([4,5,6])
```

Comment: [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) seem to prefer using `reindex` explicitly passing the new index as a kwarg

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/series.html#reindexing-selection-label-manipulation

Comment: @g-anderson  I clarified the original question to explain why reindex doesn't work. I don't understand which of the functions from your link would work - could you please clarify? Thanks

Comment: Do you have a reference for your working method not being recommended? `index` is s property and it builds an `Index` from the thing you assign. You got `Int64Index([4, 5, 6], dtype='int64')`. I think you already have the normal way to assign an index.

Comment: what is wrong with `s.index = [....]` You can change the index anytime by doing s.index

Comment: @joe-ferndz I had a vague recollection about that being discouraged, but maybe I am wrong

Answer (score 2):

Lets Try `.set_axis` as an alternative because `.set_index` is a dataframe method and not a series method

```
s.set_axis([4,5,6], axis=0)
```

Can also use np.arange if you don't want to hard code values

```
s.set_axis(np.arange(len(s))+4, axis=0)
```

Comment: This works in a method chain for both `DataFrame` and `Series`.

Comment: Note that there's no need to provide the axis arg since, with respect to Series.set_axis(), the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.set_axis.html) state: "For Series this parameter is unused and defaults to 0".

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reindex, I recommend you just do a s.index with the new index list.

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series(data =['a','b','c'], index=range(1,4))
print (s)
s = s.append(pd.Series(list('defg')))
s.index= range(11,19)
print (s)
```

Here's the output:
Initial Series:

```
1    a
2    b
3    c
dtype: object
```

After the append:

```
1    a
2    b
3    c
0    d
1    e
2    f
3    g
4    h
dtype: object
```

As you know appending just starts index from 0 again if we don't give an index.

Now if I want to set the index to new values, I can just do s.index. The result of s.index for range(11,19) is:

```
11    a
12    b
13    c
14    d
15    e
16    f
17    g
18    h
dtype: object
```